# Google authenticator MFA codes aren't working in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, multi-factor-authentication

I want to enable MFA to use sudo commands on my laptop running Debian. I followed steps to enable this, and had the verification codes working for the desktop log in. But in terminal it keeps saying "Sorry, try again." when I enter the verification code. I do not need it enabled for SSH.

Here are the steps I've tried, I followed a guide to enable MFA on Debian:

- I installed the google lib pam module.
- I ran `google-authenticator` to set up MFA, scanning the QR code with my phone.
- During set up I entered an authenticator code which was successful. (The first time it was not successful as Debian did not have system time synced. I had to go through extra steps to get the system time to automatically update which fixed this issue).
- I also set it so it can uses codes either side of the current code, so time sync should not be an issue.

I then added the `auth required google_pam_authenticator.so` line to various files in `/etc/pam.d/` directory with mixed success. (I only added it to one file at a time)

- Adding it to `common-session` should enable MFA for desktop login, which it does and works fine.
- Adding to `common-auth` should enable MFA for desktop login and sudo, but it only works for desktop login.
- Adding to `sudo` as follows:

```
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Also brings up the same error; ""Sorry, try again." whenever I enter a verification code. The backup "scratch codes" also do not work, which I believe aren't time related.

I have tried deleting the google authenticator config and setting everything up multiple times. Each time I checked that the `.google-authenticator` file in my home directory matches what I'm using in my phone app.

Comment: I'd still check your server's time to ensure it's correct; a 30-60 second skew is enough to break things.

Comment: I did check, they are only a second or two off. The codes also work on the login screen. And I have set it up to allow for a 4 minute skew during the guided set up of `google-authenticator`